# .NET counterpart of Java's locale's variant: does it exist?

Tags: .net, localization, locale

Are there localisation mechanisms available under .NET (out of the box) that support something like Java's locale's variant?
Beside the language and country I would like to be able to have a variant, say, per users' domain.
My users represent various domains and their vocabulary varies. I was trying something like "en-US-domain1", but to no avail.
I do not want to reinvent the wheel, if one exists.

I would be grateful for any insights you might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom `CultureInfo` ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304507/create-custom-culture-in-asp-net)) and then have resource strings localized using that culture.