# What if a Language has no Language Code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, resources

When it comes to Localisation of MVC applications ... How does one go about localising an application into a language where that language has no language code? [Not in the MSDN](http://goo.gl/JSzbz) at least !

There are hundreds of such languages, but take [Kurdish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdish_language) as an example.

Comment: kur is the ISO 639-3 language code for Kurdish

Comment: so one can ignore the fact that the MSDN does not acknowledge that language code?

Comment: See here for a list of language codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: I think you're wrong about it. I really don't think that there are many languages left without language code assigned. Especially because, there existing standards assign codes even to extinct languages, that is the ones nobody use nowadays. I can't imagine where you can find "hundreds" of missing ones.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong. I just meant in the MSDN CultureInfo class I guess. I'll try and be more careful next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a similar question here:

- [creating a custom CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916940/creating-custom-cultureinfo-for-country-language-combination)

That thread points to two (hopefully) useful resources:

- [new CultureInfo from an existing CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304507/create-custom-culture-in-asp-net)
- [custom CultureInfo tutorial](http://en.csharp-online.net/Using_Custom_Cultures%E2%80%94Uses_for_Custom_Cultures)

Comment: Thank you, very useful, but where would that code go? I am a bit of a n00b.

Comment: It should be run from the Application_Start method in the Global.asax file.