# Using a new cultureinfo currency in Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, currency, cultureinfo

Thanks for answering my previous question, but I have a new one: I am writing a program that output monetary values/data, I want to know how to make my program format my value in other currency not presently listed in vs 2010 like Nigerian Naira, Ghana's Cedis... the question really is how do I create a new cultureinfo language and currency symbol

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916940/creating-custom-cultureinfo-for-country-language-combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new CultureInfo via the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class.
Look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.register.aspx) for examples.