# How do I support Serbian locale in Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to support Serbian localization within Unity (2017.2.1f1) using.Net 3.5. I'm aware of the fact that this version of .net apparently doesn't support Serbian locale, however, I've seen numerous sources suggest that you can make a culture if it's not officially supported. I'm unsure if this is possible using Unity, and the documentation is of very limited help.

I've been considering upgrading to .net 4, as this apparently supports Serbian, however, this is quite a large cost to incur currently so I'd rather do that as a last resort. Additionally, if the 4 platforms I'm deploying to (Android, Windows, Mac, and iOS) all support this locale, then I'm wondering if there's a way to do it natively alongside Unity? Further to this, my code doesn't rely too much on localization, only pluralization in a few places, so as a less robust option, I wonder if there's a locale I could use in place of Serbian?

I don't believe using `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder` is an option here, due to my use case of Unity across multiple platforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating custom CultureInfo for country, language combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916940/creating-custom-cultureinfo-for-country-language-combination)

Comment: “Upgrading to .NET 4” - how are you still using 3.5?!

Comment: The version of Unity I'm using only has experimental support for .net 4>.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that binds you to using unity 2017? starting from the unity 2018 release (latest 2018.3) .net 4.x is fully supported (and 3.5 deprecated). It may be worth your time to upgrade a unity version so you have the out of the box support for it that .net 4.x brings, instead of trying to implement it yourself.

Comment: Only the update cost. I have numerous apps. on 4 different platforms, being shipped from this version, the QA and release cost means it's not a priority right now but by the sounds of it, it may have to be.