# Is it possible to manually specify fallback cultures with .NET resx globalization?

Tags: c#, globalization, resx

I am working on a website where we need to deploy partially-tested translations (resx key-value pairs) to some users for review before rolling out those translations for all users.

One potential way to do this would be a to create a "beta" culture for a specific language and populate that culture's resx file with these untested translations. Then, we could switch our test users to this culture so that they can see the beta translations. Thus, I would like to establish a fallback chain like:

beta-chinese => chinese => default (english)

Is this possible within the .NET/ASP.NET resx architecture? If so, how do I set this up?

Comment: So, if you switch the users to the beta culture, why do you need a fallback?

Comment: @Remy: the beta culture only has a small subset of the total resx keys at any given time (the ones currently being worked on). We don't want to have to keep a (mostly duplicate) copy of each culture just to support beta testing

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following resources it should work:

Resources.resx

Resources.zh.resx

Resources.zh-BT.resx

See here too:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

If you named your Chinese resources zh-CN then I think it will not work.

For zh-BT you have to create a custom culture:
[Create custom culture in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304507/create-custom-culture-in-asp-net)

Comment: Unfortunately, we have multiple chinese translations, so we can't use the last portion of the culture for this.

Comment: Hmm, then I'm out of ideas.