# Gridviewcell showing wrong thousand seperator

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a radgridview (is from telerik, but it's like a DataGrid) with multiple decimal columns. They should be shown like this: 10'000.00

That's working correctly with this:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Total" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Total, StringFormat=N2}">
```

But if I edit the cell it is show in a wrong format:
[image]

So I tried to create a CellEditTemplate:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Betrag Holzbau" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Total, StringFormat=N2}">
     <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat=N2}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
 </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

But this shows a wrong thounsand separator (’ instead of '):
[image]

How can I set the format always to this 10'000.00

Comment: What culture are you using? Try to set the `Language` property of the `RadWatermarkTextBox` or use a `TextBox`.

Comment: I'm using swiss culture (de-ch). I already tried a textbox but it won't work with it.

Comment: Did you try to set the `Language` property to "de-ch"? Did you try to set the `DataStringFormat` property of the column?

Comment: I set `DataFormatString="{}{0:N2}"` on the column. But it didn't work. Should I set Language only on the Textbox or on the RadGridView

Comment: On the `TextBox`.

Comment: I found out that the Textbox has the correct culture. But the `CurrencyGroupSeparator` is wrong. That's very curios. Can I change this only for my textboxes?

Comment: The culture of the textbox and the Thread is de-CH. The `CurrencyGroupSeperator` is showing ’ instead of ' . But as I know the swiss german useses ' as seperator. This is also set in my Setting of my Windows. So it's wrong in my opinion. Could the culture use the wrong seperator?

Comment: Wrong or not, it is what it is. Maybe you want to create your own custom culture or convert the value yourself.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for your help. With the CellEditTemplate I could change it and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the `Language` property of the `TextBox` to a culture in the `CellEditTemplate` to format the number according to that culture.

Then you "only" need to find a culture that uses `'` or [create your own custom culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304507/create-custom-culture-in-asp-net).

Another option may to format the value yourself, for example using a value converter.